# after installing react-router-dom the web app shpws error in terminal on starting

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to create reactjs apps and every time ,I install react-router-dom ,the web app shows error in terminal when I do npm start .

Here is the error

```
sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! routeroute@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the routeroute@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rock/.npm/_logs/2019-03-16T10_04_47_549Z-debug.log
```

I tried doing rm -rf node_modules and then again installing but it doesn't seem to be working .
When I did npm install again ,
I got this error

```
npm ERR! path /home/rock/Desktop/routeroute/node_modules/browserslist/cli.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/rock/Desktop/routeroute/node_modules/browserslist/cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rock/.npm/_logs/2019-03-16T10_19_02_250Z-debug.log
```

Here is the dependecies for package.json

```
  {
  "name": "routeroute",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you update the post with package.json file?

Comment: @NikolaTrajkovic Yes, I did that .

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your version of npm:

1. Try with this command: **npm i -g npm**
2. Or you can use this: **npm install npm@latest -g**

Comment: Ok .I will do that .My concern is that as I see it has -g it will change npm global .I have many other projects running fine with the np have .Will they not get affected ?

Comment: Yes you -need to update npm on global level. Good question, I m not sure.
If you update npm on the new version, that can't reflect bad on your older project, don't worry about that. If that is your question.

Comment: Hey .It still didn't work .I go the same error .I update version .Removed all old modules and did npm install but same error ,

Comment: Do you used Yarn for creating the project?

Comment: Can you try again, remove node_modules folder, and remove package-lock.json 
then execute npm install.